# Compare Cell value with Array content

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, if-statement

My goal is to check in one column if each cell contains (besides other values) a letter from my array.

The cells look something like "123A".
My array contains values A, C, D, X, Y, Z.
Both just example values.
Note my if-statement should be true if the cell contains any of the letters, so for the example it should be true.
For the cell Value "123B" it should be false (no B in array).

I found a "IsinArray" Function that appears to be working but checks for specific values.

What I would need is closer to ---> `"*" & IsinArray & "*"`

The function I found looks like this:

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function
```

Also my For statement to loop through the column is working (I'd say ^^)

I am also open to "creative" solutions if you have any ideas how to do it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could swop it around

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim testArray(), cellValue As String, rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")    '<== contains
    testArray = Array("A", "C", "D", "X", "Y", "Z")
    Debug.Print IsInArrayValue(testArray, rng)
End Sub

Public Function IsInArrayValue(ByVal testArray As Variant, ByVal rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, testString As String
    testString = rng.Text
    If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        IsInArrayValue = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = LBound(testArray) To UBound(testArray)

        If InStr(testString, testArray(i)) > 0 Then
            IsInArrayValue = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    IsInArrayValue = False
End Function
```

---

If using as an UDF you could either pass the array in as shown above or if array doesn't change you could move into the function itself. Personally, I prefer passing the array as an argument to the function as more flexible. I can't work out where your row to copy is coming from. Your comment posted as an answer uses a j variable that doesn't appear to be involved in the shown loop and the row is copied from another sheet. So below will not work directly but gives you a framework.

```
Public Function IsInArrayValue(ByVal rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, testString As String, testArray()
    testArray = Array("A", "C", "D", "X", "Y", "Z")
    testString = rng.Text
    If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        IsInArrayValue CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = LBound(testArray) To UBound(testArray)

        If InStr(testString, testArray(i)) > 0 Then
            IsInArrayValue = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    IsInArrayValue = False
End Function
```

Call:

[image]

---

The comment below is looks like a new question but you probably want something like:

```
Dim loopRange As Range, rng As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Filter")
    Set loopRange = .Range(.Cells(1, VarNutzerSpalte), .Cells(VarAnzahlZeilen, VarNutzerSpalte))
End With

For Each rng In loopRange
   If IsInArrayValue(ArrAuswahlNutzer, rng) Then
       rng.EntireRow.Copy  '<= use Union to gather range if all being pasted in a block somewhere
   End If
Next
```

A union version might looks like:

```
Dim loopRange As Range, rng As Range, unionRng As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Filter")
    Set loopRange = .Range(.Cells(1, VarNutzerSpalte), .Cells(VarAnzahlZeilen, VarNutzerSpalte))
End With

For Each rng In loopRange
   If IsInArrayValue(ArrAuswahlNutzer, rng) Then
   If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
       Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, rng)
   End If
       Set unionRng = rng  '<= use Union to gather range if all being pasted in a block somewhere
   End If
Next

If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then

    unionRng.EntireRow.Copy  'destination for paste

End If
```

Comment: Hi There, thanks alot but i have a small issue
If the function is true then i want to copy the whole row. Normally i would work with a for loop that and say row(i).copy but well, how to implement that?
Here is my current Code

`    'The range should be fine (need it variable)
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Filter").Range(Cells(1, VarNutzerSpalte), Cells(VarAnzahlZeilen, VarNutzerSpalte))
    
    'For i = 1 to VarAnzahlZeilen
    If IsInArrayValue(ArrAuswahlNutzer, rng) Then
        'Here I want to copy the Current Row
    End If
    'Next i`
I guess this version wont work

Comment: That becomes a new question really. rng needs to be a single cell so you would be looping all cells in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Filter").Range(Cells(1, VarNutzerSpalte), Cells(VarAnzahlZeilen, VarNutzerSpalte))  . See edit above in case helps.

Comment: Thanks alot, i tried something different (and ugly) but i guess it could work :)

Comment: Are you copying all the rows to the same place? It is possible and efficient, in that case, to copy all rows into a Union range object and paste in one go.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim s As String, i As Integer
    Dim a As Variant
    For i = 1 To Len(stringToBeFound)
        s = Mid(stringToBeFound, i, 1)
        For Each a In arr
            If s = a Then
                IsInArray = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next a
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question (corrections/feedback to this solution is welcome of course)

I tried it like this and i guess it should work (cant really test because other parts of my makro arent working)
It is kinda unecessary complicated and maybe slow but id say it could work:

```
For i = 1 To VarAnzahlZeilen
    Set rng = Worksheets("Filter").Range(Cells(i, VarNutzerSpalte), Cells(i, VarNutzerSpalte))

    If IsInArrayValue(ArrAuswahlNutzer, rng) Then
        Worksheets("Import").Rows(j).Copy
        Worksheets("Filter").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If

Next i
```

Uses this function by QHarr (with only the array name changed)

```
Public Function IsInArrayValue(ByVal testArray As Variant, ByVal rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, testString As String
    testString = rng.Text
    If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        IsInArrayValue = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = LBound(testArray) To UBound(testArray)

        If InStr(testString, testArray(i)) > 0 Then
            IsInArrayValue = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    IsInArrayValue = False
End Function
```

Thanks alot @ QHarr and also @ Dy.Lee !

Comment: Hi! This area is for answers. Also, in the above your are not changing the row j at last where I can see anyway. How is j related to your loop?